# Random Forest grow

Tags: performance, matlab, random-forest

i work in this little function to prepare a index for a random forest train. With this function i get a index for a set of examples and a index for a subset of features for the examples. I found the code a little bit slow, is there a better and faster way to do this?

Here is my code

```
    function [idx_linhas, idx_features ] = prepararsementes(X,features,nseeds,treesize)
    %Esta função prepara os index para a "semeadura" de uma random forest
    idx_linhas = nan(nseeds,treesize);
    idx_features= nan(nseeds,features);

    for idx=1:nseeds
    [~,idx_linhas(idx,:)] = datasample(X,treesize,'Replace',true);
    end


    for idx=1:nseeds
    [~,idx_features(idx,:)] = datasample(X,features,2);
    end

    idx_linhas = idx_linhas.';

    end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here, but it seems that you call `datasample` 2xn times. Perhaps try reducing that?

Comment: This is because i need to generate n set of samples, one time for examples "rows" and the other of columns

Comment: After getting this indexes i use then in another function

       for i =1:99
       [Theta1{i},Theta2{i}] =       looplearning(5000,100,2,x(idxl(:,i),idxf(i,:)),y(idxl(:,i)),test(:,idxf(i,:)),ytest,0,35,'EURUSD','E:/Data/Majors');
end

Comment: If you need to get n samples, with replace, then why not simply get 1 sample that is n times bigger and then `reshape` the results? I can't try it but it may be faster. Edit: Just like @Rody suggested actually.

Comment: The second sample is in another dim of the matrice, so the range of the indexes is smaller(in this case).

Comment: You don't need to do it all at once, just do it 2 times instead of 2n times. For the second part only feed datasample the relevant data.

Comment: i need n subsets not just one because of this i call n times

I need two matrices one is for slice the trainning set in rows and the second is to slice the trainning set in columns

if nseeds(read number of sub trainning sets of X) = 10 ,features = 50 ,treesize = 5000 X(35000x19700)


I need to get index so i will get 10 5000X10 matrice U , that is a slice of X

idx_features is per line(each line is the indexes for a subset of features)
idx_line is per column(each column is the indexes fora subset of examples of X)

U = X(idx_linhas(:,1),idx_features(1,:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function [idx_linhas, idx_features] = prepararsementes(X, features, nseeds, treesize)

    % instead of loop, call datasample() only once, and reshape
    % note that ('replace', true) is the default, so I omitted that

    [~,idx]      = datasample(X, nseeds*treesize);
    idx_linhas   = reshape(idx, nseeds, treesize).';  

    [~,idx]      = datasample(X, nseeds*features, 2);
    idx_features = reshape(idx, nseeds, features);

end
```

Statistically speaking, I think the outcomes should be the same, since you have no specific weighting and you draw with replacements in both cases.

Comment: Rody, tks for the answer, but there is a little problem, in the second sample the range that data is allowed to be sampled is smaller, so i need to mantain indexes inside this range.

Comment: @LeonardoHermoso: uhhhm...how is that reflected in your original code?

Comment: This is how i use th indexes:

for i =1:nseeds
[Theta1{i},Theta2{i}] = looplearning(features,neuronios,labels,x(idxl(:,i),idxf(i,:)),y(idxl(:,i)),test(:,idxf(i,:)),ytest,0,35,'EURUSD','E:/Data/Majors');
end

Comment: @LeonardoHermoso: Ah, OK i think I get what you mean. I can't test this properly, but I think the range is OK; I sample from the same X in the same dimension (2), so the indices should be fine; I just sample more often in one go.

Comment: Rody, i need to sample in two directions. The first is for row, in this particular case i have a 35768x19700 matrice... each line is a example and each column a feature, so the idx_linhas is a bunch of lines or examples of mydataset(range 1-35768). The idx_features is a bunch of features(range 1-19700), this way i can create a cart of tree and features to be trainned

Comment: @LeonardoHermoso: so `size(X) = [linhas features]`? If this is so, why are they separate inputs to the function then? Also, I *think* that I do exactly as you describe...Have you tested my code? What are the errors you get?

Comment: >> idx = prepararsementes2(x,99,5000);
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

I need two matrices one is for slice the trainning set in rows and the second is to slice the trainning set in columns

if nseeds(read number of sub trainning sets of X) = 10 ,features = 50 ,treesize = 5000 X(35000x19700)


I need to get index so i will get 10 5000X10 matrice U , that is a slice of X

idx_features is per line(each line is the indexes for a subset of features)
idx_line is per column(each column is the indexes fora subset of examples of X)

U = X(idx_linhas(:,1),idx_features(1,:))

Comment: Rody, your code is right! But when i try

[idxl,idxf] = prepararsementes2(x,5000,999,5000); i get  out of memory error even have installed 24gb in my machine, but for smaller sets works very well